# Сохранить положения radiobutton

Tags: java, android

Имеется 3 radiobutton в radiogroup как сделать так чтобы после действий пользователя с кнопками допустим он выбрал третью и после закрытия приложения и вновь открытия третья и оставалось нажатой?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.example.admin.orshagoes.fragments.FragmentSettings.onResume(FragmentSettings.java:50)
   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:874)
   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
   at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4849)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: возможно [этот гид](https://metanit.com/java/android/12.2.php) поможет вам понять, как работать с PreferenceFragment

Comment: @pavlofff спасибо посмотрю почитаю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы должны сохранить значение выбранной кнопки в каком нибудь месте. Либо например в синглете, либо в SharedPreferences.

Если мы говорим про SharedPreferences то код должен быть примерно таким:

```
  mSharedPreferences = ((AppCompatActivity) mContext).getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   // получить значение
   int pointer = mSharedPreferences.getInt(key, -1);
   // положить значение
   SharedPreferences.Editor ed = mSharedPreferences.edit();
   ed.putInt(objectposition, pointer);
   ed.commit();
```

Comment: синглтон не переживет закрытие приложения.

Comment: @pavlofff согласен, но мы же не знаем какая задача стоит перед вопрошающим :) Я потому и привел код с SharedPreferences

Comment: @plesser задача такая при старте приложения должно браться положение радиобаттона и в соответствии с положение выводить нужный фрагмент типа настроек главного экрана

Comment: Ну тогда как я ответил